# Implementing MVC pattern with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-rest-framework

I was wondering how could I implement a MVC pattern on a Django Api project, when I start a django project it gives me the apps.py, admin.py, models.py and the views.py , I understand the the models, should be the "M",  and  the views the "V", but as i'm using the project like an api, the view would be an Angular or React App, so where I put the logical ? Where is the right place to put the "C" controller on a django rest framework project, is it on views.py ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand that web service (which you are going to implement with `Django`) and your client app (which you are going to implement with `Angular`) are totally different apps and they should not depend on each other. These apps will have their own `Models`, `Views` and `Controllers`.

If we are talking about some business logic that you need to store somewhere on a backend then you can use an approach where you will have an additional level (usually, people call it `services.py`) and you will import code from this layer to `views.py` and only call it there cause your views should stay clean and simple as much as possible.

In an ideal case, especially, at the start, I guess, you will not have some tricky logic and mostly your `API` will look like simple `CRUD`, so for that case, you even don't need to store additional logic somewhere you just can use `rest framework` `ViewSets` as is and store some little snippets in `utils.py`.

The bottom line is - you don't understand fundamentals that's why you asked the wrong question. And you don't need it right now. Just go and write your app and read the docs about frameworks that you are using, eventually, you will understand this topic.